# Adding dynamic color boxes with django

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to manage multiple color options for single product using Django framework. I can add single color per product but can't add multiples for single product. My model is following and I am using app 'django_colorfield' for it.

```
from django.db import models
from colorfield.fields import ColorField

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/')
    color = ColorField(default='#FF0000')
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

In my detail view I use it like this in template to get color circles:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
        <h1>{{ object.title }}</h1>
        <hr />
        <p>{{ object.description }}</p>
        <img src="{{ object.image.url }}"/>
        <div class="color" style="color: {{ object.color }}; background-color: {{ object.color }}; cursor:pointer; margin: 0; width: 15px; height: 15px; -webkit-border-radius: 100%; -moz-border-radius: 100%; border-radius: 100%;">.</div>
        <h4>{{ object.price }}</h4>
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

Please advise how to be able to add multiple colors for single product. Do I need to create a separate class for color. If yes then how to associate it with Product, like using manytomany or foreignkey? I am a beginner so please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a model *color_product*

```
class color_product(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = ColorField(default='#FF0000')
```

In template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
        <h1>{{ object.title }}</h1>
        <hr />
        <p>{{ object.description }}</p>
        <img src="{{ object.image.url }}"/>

        {% if object.color_product_set.all %}
            {% for c in object.color_product_set.all %}
                <div class="color" style="color: {{ c.color }}; background-color: {{ c.color }}; cursor:pointer; margin: 0; width: 15px; height: 15px; -webkit-border-radius: 100%; -moz-border-radius: 100%; border-radius: 100%;">.</div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        <h4>{{ object.price }}</h4>
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```